# C++ constraints enable_if vs requires

Tags: c++, templates, constraints, enable-if, c++-concepts

I just ran along the C++ *requires* keyword and want to know whether my understanding is correct so far: Both *requires* and *enable_if* offer compile time constraints for templates. If *require* constraints will be included at all.

Where *requires* offers a way of constraining function parameters, *enable_if* has the main purpose of restricting compile time translation to certain conditions of the template type itself.

Examples:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept T AdditiveGroup
{
  return requires(const T pA, const T pB)
  {
    { pA + pB }->T;
  };
};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, bool>::type
addElements(const T pA, const T pB)
{ 
  return (pA + pB);
}
```

Here the concept should work if and only if pA and pB can be added, whereas the enable_if condition restricts evaluation to integral types.

Thanks for letting me know if I got this right!

P.S.: I am not yet quite sure at all about the syntax of the *require* constraints, which seems to vary. In addition, no idea which compiler accepts them at the time being, so thanks for any hints!

Comment: The `requires` syntax comes from Concepts Lite which is not finalized yet.

Comment: I figured it is still in development. Assuming it will be considered for a future standard, I wanted to know whether I got the ideas right. Meanwhile I found this helpful article, which shows that both approaches are basically template type based: http://accu.org/index.php/journals/2198

Comment: For examples/details you can take a look at [N4377 - Programming Languages — C++ Extensions for Concepts](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf). Unfortunately [concepts didn’t make C++17](http://honermann.net/blog/2016/03/06/why-concepts-didnt-make-cxx17/) but GCC v6 supports them (via `-fconcepts` switch).

Comment: Ah, bad news not having them in C++17. Thanks a lot for the links!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, your understanding seems to be correct. Using SFINAE to constrain templates (e.g. `enable_if`) has the same essential effect of concept-constrained templates. However (as you alluded to), SFINAE has additional side-effects.

[Ville's Jacksonville paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0225r0.html) about his rationale for including concepts in C++17 does an excellent job of explaining the pitfalls of SFINAE-based constraints when compared to concepts. Essentially:

- Concepts allow constraining function arguments without turning off deduction and without disturbing the meta-arity of a constrained function template.
- Concepts make it much easier to write overloads with mutually exclusive constraints.
- Concepts enable a broad range of constraint designs, giving the interface designer various tools to decide what sort of abstractions a particular interface needs.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for the link, denotes problems I disliked but did not dare talking about! Hope we will have concepts soon. Answer upvoted!

Comment: In which way do Concepts make it easier to write overloads with mutually exclusive constraints?